# Help with Motor encoder connection with motorcontroller

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, pid-controller

I am new to building drones and bots. I started out using motors without encoders with my [Roboclaw Motor Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAoyY.jpg) for my pet project. Here is the controller's [link](http://www.ionmc.com/RoboClaw-2x30A-Motor-Controller_p_9.html). Connection seemed simple and it was working the way it was supposed to. Now I got these [new motors](https://www.servocity.com/html/313_rpm_hd_planetary_gear_moto.html#.VjuOlXyrQxM) with encoders for better control. There are 6 pins from the [encoder](https://imgur.com/XPeKILd). on top of that, I can see two metal prongs (marked M+ and M-), much like my earlier motor, connected to the motor itself. And I am confused about the connection. I don't know which pin goes where.

I tried contacting customer service to no avail. I am not super confident about trial and error either. Can anyone please explain the connection details? Thank you.

Sorry if this question seems too naive. Also, if this is not the appropriate place for this question, any pointer to where it should go will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 6 wires are 2-differential pairs for A and B channels and the power. Power is likely to be the red/black pair. The others you can figure out by connecting the power and observing the waveforms when rotating the shaft. There might be a case you can use only one wire from a pair as a single-ended connection. Otherwise you might need something like RS-422 receiver.

Comment: And `M+/-` are the motor power, of course..

Comment: I inspected closely and figured that the M+/- prongs are indeed connected to the encoder via the pcb. I am mostly confused about the rest 4 wires - green/yellow/brown/orange. Which pins do I connect them to?

Comment: On the link in your question there is a perfectly visible table that explains this and further down there is a data sheet that goes into further detail.

Comment: I understand; but I clearly lack the capability to decipher them. I just started getting myself familiar with these.

Comment: What is it about the little table of connections and wire colours you don't understand?

Comment: In the table line 4 and 5, brown and yellow are supposed to go to channel A and B respectively. Now, in my controller, I see A and B channels for two motors (I suppose) M1 and M2 each. Does pin 4 and 5 go into A and B of M1|M2? If so, then where do the power pins (Black and red, 1 and 2) go? Do they go to the +- labelled pins on the controller (right next to micro usb port)? If yes, there are two pairs of them; are they related to M1 and M2 or either works fine? And finally what about green and orange pins? Also, what does both pairs of `EN1` and `EN2` pins do in the controller?

Comment: I feel they are to be connected to the encoder (green and orange pins maybe?), but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

From page 10 of the controller data sheet you can determine the encoder power pins (+ and -). From the same page you can determine the sensor inputs A and B. These connect to the pins specified in the link table.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for some direction towards solution. I'm checking it out. Will update shortly.